# Is there any way to loop trough these numbers: -1 0, 1 0, 0 -1, 0 1

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm currently writing a chess program and trying to loop through all rook's moves. For that, I need to get these set of numbers: 
1 0 (right), -1 0 (left), 0 1 (up), 0 -1 (down).
I came up with this line of code:

```
if (this.piece == "rook" || this.piece == "queen") {
        for (var dir = -3; dir <= 3; dir += 2) {
            let checkChar = pposChar, checkNum = pposNum, m1, m2;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.step; i++) {
                if (dir == 1 || dir == -1) {
                    m1 = 0, m2 = dir;
                } else {
                    m1 = dir/Math.abs(dir), m2 = 0;
                }
                if (isLegal(checkChar, checkNum, m1, m2)) {
                    this.moves.push(isLegal(checkChar, checkNum, m1, m2));
                    checkChar += m1;
                    checkNum += m2;
                } else 
                    break;
            }
        }
 }
```

It works just fine, but it looks kind of ugly and hard to read. Is there any way to perform this cleaner or better?

Comment: I would post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mplungjan Not if it's going to be posted on Code Review. Different rules apply.

Comment: @mplungjan In that case, please take a look at [their FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) before making recommendations.

Comment: @mplungjan That discussion is surprisingly unrelated. [This](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/52915) is more relevant. Details matter, don't leave out the details on Code Review. An MCVE is stripped down too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take an array of offsets and add these values to the indices.

```
var adjacent = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0 -1]];
```